# Re-rendering/swapping templates after being removed from DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, meteor

At the moment I have the following layout:

```
<div id="main">
    {{> my_template}} 
</div>
```

Now later on I have a selector `$("#main")` and I use `html(..)` to change the content to display a record from a collection.

So now maybe it looks like so:

```
<div id="main">
    <h1>A title...</h1>
    <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

Or maybe like so (If I knew how):

```
<div id="main">
    {{> another_template}} 
</div>
```

What is the proper way of doing this so I can get my `my_template` re-rendered/swapped-out for other templates? Do I have to use `Meteor.render`? How can I do this?

**Edit:**
I need some more clarification on doing this with a template that only has HTML and no reactive templating variables. How does that get enabled/disabled using the `Session`?

```
<template name="newForm">
    <form>
        <input..>
        <textarea..></textarea>
        <!-- more fields.. -->        
    </form> 
</template>
```

How would I use `Template.newForm` to hide this? Should I still be using `Template` for this situation?

Comment: This method no longer works with blaze. Use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22918869/meteor-js-how-to-swap-partial-templates-in-and-out-of-the-main-page/22919729#22919729

Comment: @Joseph is 'blaze' the code name for a specific version?

Comment: yes: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze

Referring to the upvoted answer. It does not work this the most recent version of meteor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just put all the alternate templates next to each other:

```
<div id="main">
    {{> my_template}} 
    {{> another_template}}
    {{> yet_another_template}}
</div>
```

And just ensure in your code that you only show one of them at a time. For instance:

```
Template.my_template = function() {
  if (Session.equals("template_to_show", "my_template")) {
    return SomeCollection.find();
  }
}
Template.another_template = function() {
  if (Session.equals("template_to_show", "another_template")) {
    return SomeOtherCollection.find();
  }
}
// etc
```

Comment: Do I just do a `display:none` on a selector for the template I want to hide and vice-versa for one I want to display? What's the convention for doing that?

Comment: No, if you use the code I showed you Meteor will remove the template from the DOM when the condition for rendering it is false. You don't need to do any hiding or showing of DOM elements yourself.

Comment: How exactly does it know when the session variable was changed, or when to execute the `if`? Is there a hidden event being fired/caught?

Comment: You should check out the [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com), which explains basic principles and concepts of Meteor, including how Session works (it's a reactive variable; when it changes, dependencies are automatically triggered by Meteor).